# What's the difference between the various Open Subdiv compute types?

Tags: customization, performance, subdivision-surface

It seems there are 5 different available "compute types". what *are* these compute types? What's the difference between them?

[image: compute types for open subdiv in user preferences]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference relies in in which device the actual calculations are done. *CPU* and *OpenMP* are run on the CPU, while *GLSL Transform Feedback* and *GLSL Compute* are run on the GPU.

> - CPU - single threaded CPU implementation. it is mainly useful in cases when GPU compute is possible and threaded CPU option causes artifacts (it is unlikely to happen, but still possible).
> - OpenMP - multi-threaded CPU implementation. It is similar to threading model of old subsurf code. Use it for maximum performance in cases when GPU compute is not available.
> - GLSL Transform Feedback - uses GPU to perform calculations, has minimal requirements to video card and driver.
> - GLSL Compute - uses GPU to perform calculations, supposed to be more efficient than Transform Feedback but also has higher requirements to video card and driver.

From the wiki [r](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Nazg-gul/OpenSubdiv) ([archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312050636/http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Nazg-gul/OpenSubdiv)).

Comment: @cegaton, sorry I couldn't ask someonewithpc because it wouldn't let me.  Let me know if I'm not supposed to do that.  You're just a boss on here haha.  Would utilizing a high end graphic card under GLSL Compute give you the best results here?  Is there a difference in speed between the compute types?  Thanks guys!

Comment: @TylerDahl Yes it would. I don't have numbers, offhand, but it should.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the help man! @someonewithpc